# NavController stealing initial view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a main menu called CRViewController and in the main menu the user has 5 menu choices.  One of which is chat.  However, when I launch the app, I'm getting pushed to the Chat MenuView. I know that it's coming from my AppDelegate, but I'm not sure on how to fix this.

```
@implementation CRAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    // add any app-specific handling code here
    return wasHandled;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MenuView alloc] init]];
    navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = COLOR_TITLE;
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = COLOR_TITLETEXT;
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:COLOR_TITLETEXT};

    [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: So is MenuView the controller you want to see first? That is the one you're setting up to be first in the app delegate. Do you have other controllers set up in a storyboard?

Comment: I want to see CRViewController first.  However, if i remove MenuView and add CRViewController, the app launches to a black screen, and I don't understand why...

Comment: The Chat is done programmatically using AwesomeChat off from Github.  The chat automatically goes to a LoginView.XIB for the user to login, and then everything else is done programatically.

Comment: MainView is the chat's "chat rooms" view controller.  However, the rest of my app (excluding the Chat) has been done using storyboard.

Comment: If you have CRViewController as the initial view controller in the storyboard (or a navigation controller that it's embedded in), you shouldn't be adding any code in the app delegate. Don't mix storyboard based controller setup with app delegate setup ones. The initial view controller in the storyboard is automatically instantiated at app launch, and added as the root view controller of the window.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  I deleted that from the appdelegate, however now my nav bar at the top of my chat rooms menu is gone.

Comment: Could I put the code that I removed from my app delegate into my MenuView.M so that it returns the functionality?

Comment: If you want the CRViewController to be the first controller,and you want it to have a navigation bar, then embed it in a navigation controller in the storyboard (just select the controller, go to the editor menu, and choose embed in, then navigation controller).